# How to display customer name in header after logged in

Tags: magento-1.9, header, customer-attribute, name

How can I display customer name in the header after logged in successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your current theme and your current **header**, some themes uses different headers : `app/design/frontend/default/themek/te‌​mplate/page/html/hea‌​der.phtml` for exemple then add this:

```
<?php if ( Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
    <div class="customer-name">    
        <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName(); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Customer name display only in account page, i need to display in header part also like,   eg: Hi, Customer_Name

Comment: No, with this code the customer name will be displayed in all pages because we added it in header and the header is displayed in all pages no ? Or you want to display it just in account page ?

Comment: I need, customer name display on all pages at the header. but your code customer name display only in the account page.

Comment: actually my mistake, I placed as a wrong position. now okay, but its display like below the menu bar. how can I display on the top header?

Comment: I need https://snag.gy/PJuIT0.jpg

Comment: It's working good, how can I add "Hi" before the customer name.

Comment: `<?php echo 'Hi' .Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName(); ?>`

Comment: How can i give space between hi and customer, now its look like Hiobama

Comment: `<?php echo 'Hi'.'&nbsp;'.Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getN‌​ame(); ?>`

Comment: after added &nbsp; i am getting error, error details : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/root/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 63

Comment: look again please

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

EDIT: file location: `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/header.phtml`

Add these in this file where you want to get the name to be shown.

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>

<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName() ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where i can add these lines

Comment: @zus see my edited answer.

Comment: I need the message display at the header, like eg: hi, customer name.

Comment: please open the `header.phtml`  and find the place. then add the code.. Can't tell you the exact location in the file.. its up to you

Answer (score 1):

When the customer is logged in, you can get customer session in frontend from any phtml file.

To show customer name in header, you would need to open **header.phtml** file located at:

> app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/page/html/

folder and write below code where you want to display current logged in customer name:

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();
}
?>
```

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html,     name display only in account page, not header page.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/root/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/themek/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 176            how to solve this error

Comment: Please see updated answer. I have fixed the error.